# Show default element while loading Image

Tags: react-native

I have a component representing an user avatar that loads an image from my API.
I want it to display a default avatar (not another image) while the avatar is loading.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    loaded: false,
  };
}

render() {
  if (!this.props.uri || !this.state.loaded) {
    return (
      <DefaultAvatar />
    );
  }
  return <Image onLoad={this.onLoad.bind(this)} uri={this.props.uri} />;
}

onLoad() {
  this.setState({loaded: true});
}
```

The problem I have is that with this current code, the `Image` will never be rendered, so the state will never change. I'm unable to find a solution that would satisfy React principles and my requirements (no ghost components to load the image before displaying it).

Comment: Is the image being loaded through props?

Comment: Can't ask the image tag to load if it's not in the DOM. Can you set it to `display:none;` until loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Image.prefetch`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6774) will allow me to do what I want, thanks to everyone.

Comment: could you explain how did you do it ?

Comment: Could you explain how to do it?

Answer (score 6):

```
class LazyImage extends React.Component{
  constructor () {
    super(this.props)
    this.state = {loaded: false}
  }

  handleLoad () {
    this.setState({loaded:true})
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.img = new Image()
    this.img.onload = this.handleLoad.bind(this)
    this.img.src = this.props.src
  } 

  render () {
    return this.state.loaded?<img src={this.props.src}/>:<div>Loading...</div>
  }
}
```

You create a native `Image` element and wait for it to load. Then you render the image with react. The browser is smart and fetches it from the cache this time. Instant render!

See http://jsfiddle.net/4hq3y4ra/3/ for a demo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I checked your demo and it works great, but it doesn't work for me as React and React-native are more different than what I thought. I will edit my question to reflect that

Comment: Can't help you with that, sorry. But you may want to create a new question and leave this one as is.

Comment: This is great a great answer! Why is no-one voting this up?

Comment: Working Great! what about react native. handLoad does not called in case of react native

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways this can be achieved, however to keep things simple, you can use a literal condition to toggle default avatar and the actual image.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    loaded: false,
  };
}

onLoad(dataUri) {
if(dataUri !== undefined){
    this.setState({loaded: true});
  }

},

render() {

    return (
          <Image  onLoad={this.onLoad} uri={this.state.loaded ? this.props.uri : 'default-avatar'} />
       );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it doesn't work in my case as `DefaultAvatar` is another component, not a default uri I could use. :/